# Show only one Category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post which is assigned to different categories. 
I created a loop

```
<div class="col-sm-12 ">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<section class="row marginbottomclass">

<div class="col-sm-4 thumbnailimage">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8">
<h1><?php the_title( ); ?></h1>
<small><?php the_category("," );?></small>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

</div>


</section>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

But this loop getting all the category of post. While i only want to show one category. I don't want to show all the category that this post assigned to.

I tried different

```
<?php $parentscategory ="";
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
$parentscategory .= ' <a href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . 
 '" title="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</a>, ';
}
}
echo substr($parentscategory,0,-2); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to to use [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms), this will grab all the categories attached to the post and put them in an array.

```
<?php
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "all"));
echo $term_list[0]->description ;
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress3\wp-content\themes\sampletheme\page-home.php on line 163, I get this error